# Is it possible to search mail for strings?

Tags: gmail, iphone

Is it possible to perform advanced searching on the native iPhone Gmail client? Search for mail containing "some string" or mail sent by, from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes it can.

You can do any search that gmail supports:

`from:myemail@mydomain.com "searchtime"` produced the following search results (which are correct):

[image]

Examples of what you can do:

`subject:(Search Term)`

To exclude a term you can do:

`-Windows`

And pretty much anything normal Gmail supports.

Comment: This is an iPod UI.  I see no search magnifying glass icon on the iPhone.  So unless I missed something, the answer does not help.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Interesting, I'll need to check on my Mom's iPhone and update my answer.